# Mysql Query running very slow

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql database with **7 tables**.My problem is there are millions of records in database, the following query is taking lot of time.what should i do?

```
(SELECT 'res' AS TBL
      , mlsnum
      , streetname
      , streetnum
      , listdate
      , gpext_latitude
      , gpext_longitude
      , zipcode
      , listprice
      , beds
      , bathsfull
      , sqftbldg
      , modified
      , yearbuilt
   FROM rets_property_res
  WHERE liststatus = "active")
  UNION 
    ALL
(SELECT 'rnt' AS TBL
      , mlsnum
      , streetname
      , streetnum
      , listdate
      , gpext_latitude
      , gpext_longitude
      , zipcode
      , listprice
      , beds
      , bathsfull
      , sqftbldg
      , modified
      , yearbuilt
   FROM rets_property_rnt
  WHERE liststatus = "active")
  UNION  
    ALL
(SELECT 'lnd' AS TBL
      , mlsnum
      , streetname
      , streetnum
      , listdate
      , gpext_latitude
      , gpext_longitude
      , zipcode
      , listprice
      , NULL AS BEDS
      , NULL AS BATHSFULL
      , NULL AS SQFTBLDG
      , modified
      , NULL AS YEARBUILT
   FROM rets_property_lnd
  WHERE liststatus = "active")
  UNION
    ALL
(SELECT 'hir' AS TBL
      , mlsnum
      , streetname
      , streetnum
      , listdate
      , gpext_latitude
      , gpext_longitude
      , zipcode
      , listprice
      , beds
      , bathsfull
      , sqftbldg
      , modified
      , yearbuilt
   FROM rets_property_hir
  WHERE liststatus = "active")
  UNION
    ALL
(SELECT 'cnd' AS TBL
      , mlsnum
      , streetname
      , streetnum
      , listdate
      , gpext_latitude
      , gpext_longitude
      , zipcode
      , listprice
      , beds
      , bathsfull
      , sqftbldg
      , modified
      , yearbuilt
   FROM rets_property_cnd
  WHERE liststatus = "active")
  UNION 
    ALL
(SELECT 'mul' AS TBL
      , mlsnum
      , streetname
      , streetnum
      , listdate
      , gpext_latitude
      , gpext_longitude
      , zipcode
      , listprice
      , NULL AS BEDS
      , NULL AS BATHSFULL
      , sqftbldg
      , modified
      , yearbuilt
   FROM rets_property_mul
  WHERE liststatus = "active")
  ORDER 
     BY listdate DESC
  LIMIT 0, 48
```

Comment: Provide proper DDLs and the EXPLAIN. Also, consider having one table instead of 7, but principally for ease of management rather than performance.

Comment: Add an `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clause to each query. (Since the entire query has a LIMIT 48, there's no need to return more than 48 rows from each SELECT.  Also, since the outer query is ordering the rows by `listdate`, before applying the LIMIT, do the same thing in each SELECT. Be sure that an appropriate index used, to avoid an (expensive) "Using filesort" operation on each SELECT. (The outer query is still going to need to do a "Using filesort", but with only 48 rows returned from each SELECT, that operation will be fast.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the queries are different.  Try replacing the `UNION` with `UNION ALL`.  Not having to remove duplicates should be a big savings.

For more savings, then limit each subquery to 48 rows and phrase them as:

```
SELECT 'res' AS TBL, . . .
FROM rets_property_res
WHERE liststatus = 'active'
ORDER BY listdate DESC
LIMIT 48
```

With an index on each table and `(liststatus, listdate)`, the query might become blindingly fast.